# Selecting by Attributes and then clipping in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I need to determine how much area is affected by the road buffer in each land cover type. There are 15 land cover types. I am wondering if there is a way for the model to go through each land cover type and clip the buffer from it, without me needing to repeat the select by attributes process.

[image: model]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, learn to use [iterators](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm) in ModelBuilder. Since all ArcGIS Pro tools only perform operations on selected features (or all features if there is no selection) you can use the iterator tools to [repeatedly make those selections](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/working-with-iterate-feature-class-selection.htm) for you.